# Oracle Enterprise Manager - Web Interface NOT RUNNING

Tags: oracle, database-administration

When I run this command

```
emctl start dbconsole
```

I get a message

> http://intitccud-5095.interrait.info:5500/em/console/aboutApplication
>    - An instance of Oracle Enterprise Manager 10g Database Control is already running.

But when I try to open the link it says connection failed.

Please note - I had run

```
emctl status dbconsole
```

I got the below message:

> Oracle Enterprise Manager 10g Database Control Release 10.1.0.2.0
>   Copyright (c) 1996, 2004 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   http://intitccud-5095.interrait.info:5500/em/console/aboutApplication

Please help - what should I do now?

Comment: Does `intitccud-5095.interrait.info` resolve to the same IP from wherever your browser is (your PC?) and from the server where you started `dbconsole`? I'd guess it's maybe only defined in the server's `hosts` file, but if it does resolve then is it pingable, and are there firewalls between you? Can you access the IP-version of the URL?

Comment: @AlexPoole   Thanks for replying . I can ping intitccud-5095.interrait.info   . But I have yet to see if I can ping the IP version . will let you know once I have done that .

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https too with same link?